# Compute the adjoint of an operator in Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, adjoint-operators

I have the following question. In the Hilbert space $l^2$, consider the operator $Tx=(\frac{x_n+x_{n+1}}{2})_n$ and $x=(x_n)_n$. Compute the adjoint of operator $T$.

I tried to find $T^*$ such that $(Tx,y)=(x,T^*y)$ through representing $x$ in series such that $x=\Sigma_{k=1}^\infty(x,e_k)e_k $. Then, I'm stuck.

Comment: Hint: $T := \frac{1}{2}(I + R)$ where $R$ is the right shift operator defined by $(Tx)_n = x_{n+1}$ and $I$ the identity. Try finding the adjoints of the two operators separately.

Comment: The adjoint is defined through $\langle x, T^* y\rangle = \langle Tx , y\rangle$, so you have to work on the RHS in order to write it as $\sum_n x_n \cdot (\text{some function of the $y_n$s})$.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two ways of solving this problem

**Hint 1**: View $T$ as an infinite matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix}1/2 & 0 & 0 & \dots \\1/2 & 1/2 & 0 & \dots \\ 0 & 1/2 & 1/2 & \dots \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots\end{pmatrix}$$

What would you get when you calculate the adjoint as if it was a finite matrix?

**Hint 2:** Let $S$ be a right shift operator on $l^2$. Then $T = 1/2(S+1)$ where $1$ is the identity operator. Then
$$T^* = 1/2 (S^* + 1^*) = 1/2(S^* + 1)$$

What is the adjoint operator of a right shift operator? (Your intuitive guess is correct).